# Change android window size with setScaleX() setScaleY()

Tags: android, view, android-windowmanager

I am adding a view using the WindowManager.

In the `WindowManager.LayoutParameters` I am setting both width and height to WRAP_CONTENT as the content should dictate how large the view should be.

However, I am allowing the user to adjust the overall size of the layout.

Then, when I create the layout, I simply apply the saved scale value and viola it shows the newly resized view.

The problem is that despite scaling the actual view I add as shown below:

```
myView.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
myView.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
mWindowManager.addView(myView, params);
```

There still seems to be some sort of "container" around my shrunk view.

So I figured instead of using `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()`, to instead add a runnable to my view to run after its done drawing and calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` then using my `scaleFactor` value to compute the new height and width. This works, but now things are getting cut off because `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()` actually shrinks *everything* inside the view. The entire `Paint` object is shrunk including text, space between text and everything.

Does anyone know how I can make the absolute dimensions the same size as the shrunk view?

EDIT: So after messing around with this. What I believe I need to do is figure out how to resize the parent layout and allowing its children to be clipped instead of resized.

For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the layout above, I scale the `TextView` object using `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()` this causes the textView to be scaled but doesn't change its actual dimensions.

What I need to do then, is get the dimensions of the `RelativeLayout` and multiply it by the float scale value. This will get the new dimensions. Then I need to update those dimensions WITHOUT changing the dimensions of the `TextView` oject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured this out and posting answer and code.

When using `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()` it would scale it according to the view's center. This would cause the view's top and left positions to shrink or grow without changing the actual dimensions of the view.

So to compensate, we must take the child view (`textView1`) and move it to the left and up how ever much we shrunk it by.

Here is the code to do this:

```
RelativeLayout parent; //THis is the parent view that you added with a WindowManager object.
TextView textView1; //This is the child view of our parent. For this example, I am using a TextView.
float factor; //This is the amount we scaled our view by.
parent.post(new Runnable() { //When you post a runnable to a view, it runs after the view is drawn and measured.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int newWidth = Math.round(parent.getWidth() * factor), newHeight = Math.round(parent.getHeight() * factor); //Calculate what the new height and width will be for the parent view to get resized to.
        WindowManager.LayoutParams pp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams)parent.getLayoutParams(); //Get an instance of the parent LayoutParams so we can set the new height and width measurements.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ch = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)chatHead.getLayoutParams(); //Get the child's layout parameters so we can adjust the margins as needed.
        int diffX = parent.getWidth() - newWidth, diffY = parent.getHeight() - newHeight; //Calculate the difference in sizes from the newly scaled size to the old size.
        diffX = -Math.round(diffX / 2); //Calculate the amount of space needed to move the child view inside its parent. The negative sign is needed here depending how you calculate the differences.
        diffY = -Math.round(diffY / 2); //Same as above, but for the height.
        ch.setMargins(diffX, diffY, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE); //Set the new margins for the child view. This will move it around so it is anchored at the top left of the parents view. 
        rootChatHead.updateViewLayout(chatHead, ch); //Apply the new parameters.
        pp.width = newWidth; //Set the parent's new width.
        pp.height = newHeight; //Set the parent's new height.
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(rootChatHead, pp); //Update the parent view.
}
```

Now our view scaled down and the container's size has been adjusted to take up any extra space caused by the scaling of our child view.

This method ALSO works if you scale the child view higher. It will readjust the parent's size to accommodate the new size of the child.